# Use WPF app process handle to register a global hotkey

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

So I'm trying to use [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) to register a new hotkey, but I'm getting ERROR_WINDOW_OF_OTHER_THREAD when passing Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle as a handle. The reason I don't want to use a handle of a specific Window is because at that point there don't exist any Windows yet, so I just want to register the hotkey with the process itself, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is the error I'm getting because I'm not using a handle to a specific Window, or is it related to something else?

Comment: Create a [Message-Only Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only) for use with [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I think this worked

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

RegisterHotKey expects an HWND (i.e., a Window handle), not a process handle. While they may be identical data-structures, they have different semantics.

RegisterHotkey ensures that the registering window receives relevant WM_HOTKEY messages - and without a window (i.e, an HWND), there is no corresponding window message loop in which WM_HOTKEY would be processed.